# Infopath forms 2010 to 2013 migration issue

Tags: infopath, migration

I need to migrate InfoPath forms 2010 to SP 2013. Now in 2010 InfoPath forms are connected to data connection library & having classic authentication. Since SP 2013 doesn't support classic authentication what are the issues should come to handle? What should be correct strategy & steps for this migration?